# ADFS 2.0 Saml response does not contain Assertion in mobile sometimes

Tags: mobile, saml, adfs, assertions

We are SP who authenticates users from ADFS 2.0 via SAML 2.0 protocol. Our setup works in desktop browser. It works on mobile app as well but it fails sometimes for users, and it fails everytime for few users. We do get SAML response in failed cases as well but that does not contain Assertion tag which should have user information.

Here is sample decoded Response from ADFS Server in failed case.

```
<samlp:Response ID="_c4ae8ed6-5ded-4b36-bce5-254c9b1f0220" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2015-08-05T08:56:22.406Z" Destination="https://example.mindtickle.com/login/ssosaml" Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:unspecified" InResponseTo="_b1fb8044-d3ba-4920-a9aa-eba90e72fa1d" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
<Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://example.com/adfs/services/trust</Issuer>
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
        <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
        <ds:Reference URI="#_c4ae8ed6-5ded-4b36-bce5-254c9b1f0220">
            <ds:Transforms>
                <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /></ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
            <ds:DigestValue>PINWa01Qonu+38cUtEWPb4tqDqnq2MQh2JAgAQFQt2o=</ds:DigestValue>
        </ds:Reference>
    </ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:SignatureValue>ZRFLQ1G22GiOOSmgAmR3kfbxdVbazB3OrXZdOZVXM/rKFVIpFD3bx1V9ToMGkd1MjtQ1EG3cGUDwaATg1TiZCULJa+q/THbT0hifi0yviwnehCjzgMbUEDpUejGWldbFIempnif3gdKJcG6XUvpqoJPoo7/w5rlyP7bb+W92Qamcn4XAZ18+sEu7gaZLGFP+p0AL6ofWg0IJoDuljrhk2/j45O+/2a8DO3ogSfpjTCq0xhWloanXuqWEXRFRkKOumXGAiq5gdwyOHxBRNPBnldgDSdstmVqLNeeXJBW+LqGDJaQTGSnu3ibV8eAlSU4nu58iiNA4AsysdJCNp8Ascw==</ds:SignatureValue>
    <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:X509Data>
            <ds:X509Certificate>MIIC...</ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
    </KeyInfo>
</ds:Signature>
<samlp:Status>
    <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Responder" /></samlp:Status>
</samlp:Response>
```

I have noticed that after logging into ADFS, it sends cookie with redirect response. In redirected request it sends SAML response. But when it fails, It neither sends cookie, nor redirect but gives SAML response immediately. This happens in mobile app webview and some mobile browser only.

Thanks

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you find a solution.